# Sum of all arguments ever passed to counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Q4. Define a function `make_counter` that returns a counter function,
>   which takes an immutable key and a numerical value argument and
>   returns the sum of all arguments ever passed to counter with that same
>   key.

Below is the solution:

```
def make_counter():
    """Return a counter function.

    >>> c = make_counter()
    >>> c('a', 3)
    3
    >>> c('a', 5)
    8
    >>> c('b', 7)
    7
    >>> c('a', 9)
    17
    >>> c2 = make_counter()
    >>> c2(1, 2)
    2
    >>> c2(3, 4)
    4
    >>> c2(3, c('b', 6))
    17  
    """
    dict = {}   
    def counter(key, value):
        if key in dict:
            dict[key].append(value)
        else:
            dict[key] = [value]
        lst = dict[key]
        total = 0
        length = len(lst)
        for index in range(length):
            total = total + lst[index]
        return total
    return counter
    """-m doctest gives some weird failure despite all above test case pass"""
```

Can we improve this solution?

Comment: Rather than asking three questions in rapid succession, why not ask one, wait for feedback, apply it to the others *then* ask a follow-up? Also, there's no need to include all of the boiler-plate twice.

Comment: Note that the reason for your `doctest` failure is **trailing whitespace**, after the `17` for the final test. It is quite picky about these things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose another name for the dictionary besides `dict`.  Don't ever hide the name of a built-in type.

Then...

```
d = {}     
def counter(key,value):
    d[key] = d.get(key,0) + value
    return d[key]
```

You're done.  I see no need to build lists of all the passed values.